# Nested Models in Backbone.js, how to approach

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I've got the following JSON provided from a server. With this, I want to create a model with a nested model. I am unsure of which is the way to achieve this.

```
//json
[{
    name : "example",
    layout : {
        x : 100,
        y : 100,
    }
}]
```

I want these to be converted to two nested backbone models with the following structure:

```
// structure
Image
    Layout
...
```

So I define the Layout model like so:

```
var Layout = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

But which of the two (if any) techniques below should I use to define the Image model? A or B below?

**A**

```
var Image = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.set({ 'layout' : new Layout(this.get('layout')) })
    }
});
```

*or,* **B**

```
var Image = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.layout = new Layout( this.get('layout') );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I have the very same issue while I'm writing my Backbone application. Having to deal with embedded/nested models. I did some tweaks that I thought was a quite elegant solution.

Yes, you can modify the parse method to change a attributes around in the object, but all of that is actually pretty unmaintainable code IMO, and feels more of a hack than a solution.

Here's what I suggest for your example:

First define your Layout Model like so.

```
var layoutModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Then here's your image Model:

```
var imageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    model: {
        layout: layoutModel,
    },

    parse: function(response){
        for(var key in this.model)
        {
            var embeddedClass = this.model[key];
            var embeddedData = response[key];
            response[key] = new embeddedClass(embeddedData, {parse:true});
        }
        return response;
    }
});
```

Notice that I have not tampered with the model itself, but merely pass back the desired object from the parse method.

This should ensure the structure of the nested model when you're reading from the server. Now, you would notice that saving or setting is actually not handled here because I feel that it makes sense for you to set the nested model explicitly using the proper model.

Like so:

```
image.set({layout : new Layout({x: 100, y: 100})})
```

Also take note that you are actually invoking the parse method in your nested model by calling:

```
new embeddedClass(embeddedData, {parse:true});
```

You can define as many nested models in the `model` field as you need.

Of course, if you want to go as far as saving the nested model in its own table. This wouldn't be sufficient. But in the case of reading and saving the object as a whole, this solution should suffice.

Comment: This is nice.. should be the accepted answer as its far cleaner than the other approaches. Only suggestions I'd have is to capitalize the first letter of your classes that extend Backbone.Model for readability.. i.e. ImageModel and LayoutModel

Comment: @StephenHandley Thanks for the comment and your suggestion. For the information, I'm actually using this in the context of requireJS. So, to answer to the capitalization matter, the var 'imageModel' is actually returned to requireJS. And the reference to the model would be encapsulated by the following construct: 

    `define(['modelFile'], function(MyModel){... do something with MyModel})`

But you're right. I do make it a habit to reference the model by the convention you suggested.

Comment: @BobS Sorry, was a typo. Should've been response. I've fixed it, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Nice! I recommend adding this to the `Backbone.Model.prototype.parse` function. Then, all your models have to do is to define the submodel object types (in your "model" attribute).

Comment: Cool! I wound up doing something similar (notably and regrettably after I found this answer) and wrote it up here: http://blog.untrod.com/2013/08/declarative-approach-to-nesting.html
The big difference is that for deeply nested models I declare the whole mapping at once, in the root/parent model, and the code takes it from there and walks down the whole model, hydrating relevant objects into Backbone collections and models. But really a very similar approach.

Comment: Elegant solution, this should be added to Backbone itself!

Comment: Wonderful solution; I put the parse function in to a new base class,  changed 'model' to 'relatedModels' and then have reused it in practically everything.

Comment: The awesome part is that this works for embedding collections in your model as well.

Comment: Would it make sense to clone the object 'response' before modifying it?

Answer (score 16):

I'm posting this code as an example of Peter Lyon's suggestion to redefine parse.  I had the same question and this worked for me (with a Rails backend).  This code is written in Coffeescript.  I made a few things explicit for people unfamiliar with it.

```
class AppName.Collections.PostsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: AppName.Models.Post

  url: '/posts'

  ...

  # parse: redefined to allow for nested models
  parse: (response) ->  # function definition
     # convert each comment attribute into a CommentsCollection
    if _.isArray response
      _.each response, (obj) ->
        obj.comments = new AppName.Collections.CommentsCollection obj.comments
    else
      response.comments = new AppName.Collections.CommentsCollection response.comments

    return response
```

## or, in JS

```
parse: function(response) {
  if (_.isArray(response)) {
    return _.each(response, function(obj) {
      return obj.comments = new AppName.Collections.CommentsCollection(obj.comments);
    });
  } else {
    response.comments = new AppName.Collections.CommentsCollection(response.comments);
  }
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Props for the example code and suggesting overriding parse. Thanks!

Comment: would be nice to have your answer in real JS

Comment: happy to have the coffeescript version, thanks. For others, try http://js2coffee.org/

Comment: If the question is real JS, an answer should be as well.

Answer (score 12):

Use `Backbone.AssociatedModel` from [Backbone-associations](https://github.com/dhruvaray/backbone-associations) :

```
    var Layout = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
        defaults : {
            x : 0,
            y : 0
        }
    });
    var Image = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
        relations : [
            type: Backbone.One,
            key : 'layout',
            relatedModel : Layout          
        ],
        defaults : {
            name : '',
            layout : null
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nice solution. There is a similar project out there too: https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure Backbone itself has a recommended way to do this.  Does the Layout object have its own ID and record in the back end database?  If so you can make it its own Model as you have.  If not, you can just leave it as a nested document, just make sure you convert it to and from JSON properly in the `save` and `parse` methods.  If you do end up taking an approach like this, I think your **A** example is more consistent with backbone since `set` will properly update `attributes`, but again I'm not sure what Backbone does with nested models by default.  It's likely you'll need some custom code to handle this.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, it was missing the `new` operator. I have edited it to fix this mistake.

Comment: Oh, then I misinterpreted your question.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I'd go with Option B if you want to keep things simple.

Another good option would be to use [Backbone-Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational). You'd just define something like:

```
var Image = Backbone.Model.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasOne,
            key: 'layout',
            relatedModel: 'Layout'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: +1 Backbone-Releational seems quite established: own website, 1.6k stars, 200+ forks.

Answer (score 6):

I use Backbone DeepModel plugin for nested models and attributes.

https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model

You can bind to change events 'n levels deep. for example:
`model.on('change:example.nestedmodel.attribute', this.myFunction);`

Answer (score 5):

CoffeeScript version of **rycfung's** beautiful answer:

```js
class ImageModel extends Backbone.Model
  model: {
      layout: LayoutModel
  }

  parse: (response) =>
    for propName,propModel of @model
      response[propName] = new propModel( response[propName], {parse:true, parentModel:this} )

    return response
```

Ain't that sweet? ;)

Comment: I don't take sugar in my JavaScript : )

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I've been experimenting with the code in [rycfung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904874/2088822), which is a great suggestion.
If, however, you do not want to `set` the nested models directly, or do not want to constantly
pass `{parse: true}` in the `options`, another approach would be to redefine `set` itself.

In **Backbone 1.0.0**, `set` is called in `constructor`, `unset`, `clear`, `fetch` and `save`.

Consider the following *super model*, for all models that need to nest models and/or collections.

```
/** Compound supermodel */
var CompoundModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    /** Override with: key = attribute, value = Model / Collection */
    model: {},

    /** Override default setter, to create nested models. */
    set: function(key, val, options) {
        var attrs, prev;
        if (key == null) { return this; }

        // Handle both `"key", value` and `{key: value}` -style arguments.
        if (typeof key === 'object') {
            attrs = key;
            options = val;
        } else {
            (attrs = {})[key] = val;
        }

        // Run validation.
        if (options) { options.validate = true; }
        else { options = { validate: true }; }

        // For each `set` attribute, apply the respective nested model.
        if (!options.unset) {
            for (key in attrs) {
                if (key in this.model) {
                    if (!(attrs[key] instanceof this.model[key])) {
                        attrs[key] = new this.model[key](attrs[key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attrs, options);

        if (!(attrs = this.changedAttributes())) { return this; }

        // Bind new nested models and unbind previous nested models.
        for (key in attrs) {
            if (key in this.model) {
                if (prev = this.previous(key)) {
                    this._unsetModel(key, prev);
                }
                if (!options.unset) {
                    this._setModel(key, attrs[key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    },

    /** Callback for `set` nested models.
     *  Receives:
     *      (String) key: the key on which the model is `set`.
     *      (Object) model: the `set` nested model.
     */
    _setModel: function (key, model) {},

    /** Callback for `unset` nested models.
     *  Receives:
     *      (String) key: the key on which the model is `unset`.
     *      (Object) model: the `unset` nested model.
     */
    _unsetModel: function (key, model) {}
});
```

Notice that `model`, `_setModel` and `_unsetModel` are left blank on purpose. At this level of abstraction you probably can't define any reasonable actions for the callbacks. However, you may want to override them in the submodels that extend `CompoundModel`.
Those callbacks are useful, for instance, to bind listeners and propagate `change` events.

---

### Example:

```
var Layout = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Image = CompoundModel.extend({
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            name: "example",
            layout: { x: 0, y: 0 }
        };
    },

    /** We need to override this, to define the nested model. */
    model: { layout: Layout },

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "_propagateChange");
    },

    /** Callback to propagate "change" events. */
    _propagateChange: function () {
        this.trigger("change:layout", this, this.get("layout"), null);
        this.trigger("change", this, null);
    },

    /** We override this callback to bind the listener.
     *  This is called when a Layout is set.
     */
    _setModel: function (key, model) {
        if (key !== "layout") { return false; }
        this.listenTo(model, "change", this._propagateChange);
    },

    /** We override this callback to unbind the listener.
     *  This is called when a Layout is unset, or overwritten.
     */
    _unsetModel: function (key, model) {
        if (key !== "layout") { return false; }
        this.stopListening();
    }
});
```

With this, you have automatic nested model creation and event propagation. Sample usage is also provided and tested:

```
function logStringified (obj) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

// Create an image with the default attributes.
// Note that a Layout model is created too,
// since we have a default value for "layout".
var img = new Image();
logStringified(img);

// Log the image everytime a "change" is fired.
img.on("change", logStringified);

// Creates the nested model with the given attributes.
img.set("layout", { x: 100, y: 100 });

// Writing on the layout propagates "change" to the image.
// This makes the image also fire a "change", because of `_propagateChange`.
img.get("layout").set("x", 50);

// You may also set model instances yourself.
img.set("layout", new Layout({ x: 100, y: 100 }));
```

**Output:**

```
{"name":"example","layout":{"x":0,"y":0}}
{"name":"example","layout":{"x":100,"y":100}}
{"name":"example","layout":{"x":50,"y":100}}
{"name":"example","layout":{"x":100,"y":100}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm late to this party, but we recently released a plugin to deal with exactly this scenario. It's called [backbone-nestify](http://revelytix.github.io/backbone-nestify/).

So your nested model remains unchanged:

`var Layout = Backbone.Model.extend({...});`

Then use the plugin when defining the containing model (using [Underscore.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)):

```
var spec = {
    layout: Layout
};
var Image = Backbone.Model.extend(_.extend({
    // ...
}, nestify(spec));
```

After that, assuming you have a model `m` which is an instance of `Image`, and you've set the JSON from the question on `m`, you can do:

```
m.get("layout");    //returns the nested instance of Layout
m.get("layout|x");  //returns 100
m.set("layout|x", 50);
m.get("layout|x");  //returns 50
```

Answer (score 2):

Use backbone-forms

It supports nested forms, models and toJSON. ALL NESTED

```
var Address = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
    street:  'Text'
    },

    defaults: {
    street: "Arteaga"
    }

});


var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
    title:      { type: 'Select', options: ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms'] },
    name:       'Text',
    email:      { validators: ['required', 'email'] },
    birthday:   'Date',
    password:   'Password',
    address:    { type: 'NestedModel', model: Address },
    notes:      { type: 'List', itemType: 'Text' }
    },

    constructor: function(){
    Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    defaults: {
    email: "x@x.com"
    }
});

var user = new User();

user.set({address: {street: "my other street"}});

console.log(user.toJSON()["address"]["street"])
//=> my other street

var form = new Backbone.Form({
    model: user
}).render();

$('body').append(form.el);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add yet another framework, you might consider creating a base class with overridden `set` and `toJSON` and use it like this:

```
// Declaration

window.app.viewer.Model.GallerySection = window.app.Model.BaseModel.extend({
  nestedTypes: {
    background: window.app.viewer.Model.Image,
    images: window.app.viewer.Collection.MediaCollection
  }
});

// Usage

var gallery = new window.app.viewer.Model.GallerySection({
    background: { url: 'http://example.com/example.jpg' },
    images: [
        { url: 'http://example.com/1.jpg' },
        { url: 'http://example.com/2.jpg' },
        { url: 'http://example.com/3.jpg' }
    ],
    title: 'Wow'
}); // (fetch will work equally well)

console.log(gallery.get('background')); // window.app.viewer.Model.Image
console.log(gallery.get('images')); // window.app.viewer.Collection.MediaCollection
console.log(gallery.get('title')); // plain string
```

You'll need [`BaseModel` from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18989596/458193) (available, if you fancy, [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/6689379#file-basemodel-js)).

Answer (score 1):

We have this problem too and a team worker has implemented a plugin named backbone-nested-attributes.

The usage is very simple. Example:

```
var Tree = Backbone.Model.extend({
  relations: [
    {
      key: 'fruits',
      relatedModel: function () { return Fruit }
    }
  ]
})

var Fruit = Backbone.Model.extend({
})
```

With this, the Tree model can access then fruits:

```
tree.get('fruits')
```

You can see more informations here:

https://github.com/dtmtec/backbone-nested-attributes