# Extract from nested attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following model attributes:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "details": {
        "name": "Sun Tzu",
        "height": "180",
    },
    "lists": [
        [{
            "coworkers": "company cool",
            "friends": "School",
        }],
        [{
            "coworkers": "company nice",
            "friends": "Childhood",
        }]
    ]
}]
```

Yes, I know it is confusing but I am trying to understand nested models.

I want to display in a view (a table row), all the `friends` of `id:1` model.
For example: `School, Childhood`.

How do I do that? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are the single-item arrays in the `lists` array?

Comment: How do you display rows? Show us what you already have.

Comment: There are lots solutions to this out there - even on SO. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535948/nested-models-in-backbone-js-how-to-approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var friends = _.chain(data)
    .findWhere({ id: 1 })
    .result('lists')
    .flatten(false)
    .pluck('friends')
    .value();
```

Comment: Should be `.pluck(0).pluck('friends')`, but +1 nonetheless

Comment: @Bergi I got the impression that each of those arrays might have multiple friends in it, so pluck(0) might not be right.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain functions to get the output you are looking for

```
console.log(_.chain(data)
    .find(function(currentObject) {
        return currentObject.id === 1;
    })
    .pick("lists")
    .flatten(false)
    .pluck("friends")
    .value());
```

**Output**

```
[ 'School', 'Childhood' ]
```