# How to do nested models in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Possibly related: [Nested Models in Backbone.js, how to approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535948/nested-models-in-backbone-js-how-to-approach)

**Code snippet:**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
], function($, Backbone){
  var GenreModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      currentGenre: null,
      availableGenres: []
    },
    initialize: function() {}
  });

  var MusicModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      genre: new GenreModel()
    },
    initialize: function() {}
  });
  // Return the model for the module
  return MusicModel;
});
```

Is the above practice acceptable? I only have one level of nested models `MusicModel.get('genre')`. The reason I am doing this is that while I want to listen to the changes in the genre model, I don't want to create another view for `genre` because it's too small. I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Hope this link would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535948/nested-models-in-backbone-js-how-to-approach

Comment: This is the way to go.